# SQL validation queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two queries I am using for testing purposes.

**Query 1 -**

```
select * from all
where primary ilike '%phy%'
limit 1;
```

**Query 2 -**

```
select * from all
where primary ilike '%org%'
limit 1;
```

How do I write these queries in the form of a script such that if `Query 1` returns a record, `Failed` is printed. For example,

```
if (Query1 returned a record) {
    print "Failed"
} else 
{
    print "Passed"
}

if (Query2 returned a record) {
    print "Failed"
} else 
{
    print "Passed"
}
```

The output I would expect is either

```
Passed
Passed
```

or

```
Passed
Failed
```

or

```
Failed
Passed
```

or

```
Failed
Failed
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve the problem at hand? Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `UNION ALL`, like:

```
select case 
    when exists (select 1 from all where primary ilike '%phy%')
        then 'Failed'
        else 'Passed'
    end result
union all 
select case 
    when exists (select 1 from all where primary ilike '%org%')
        then 'Failed'
        else 'Passed'
    end
```

Note: noth `primary` and `all` are reserved words in Postgres: don't use them in real life.

Answer (score 0):

You would normally use an `IF EXISTS()`
as:

```
IF EXISTS(select * from all
where primary like '%phy%'
limit 1;)
THEN
SELECT 'Failed'
ELSE SELECT 'Passed'
end if

union all

IF EXISTS(select * from all
where primary like '%org%'
limit 1;)
THEN
SELECT 'Failed'
ELSE SELECT 'Passed'
end if
```